# Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSHTTPURLResponse?'

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I've seen this problem a few times on this site but none of the solutions seem to work.

I am extending the alamofire request to have an array of repo objects as a result; however, I keep getting the error in the title. Here is the code:

```
 extension Alamofire.Request {
   class func repoArrayResponseSerializer() -> ResponseSerializer<Array<Repo>, NSError> {
    return ResponseSerializer { request, response, data, error in
        guard error == nil else { return .Failure(error!) }

        guard data != nil else { return .Failure(error!) }

        do {
            let jsonData: AnyObject? = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
            let json = JSON(jsonData!)

            if json.error != nil || json == nil {
                return .Failure(error!)
            }

            var repos: Array = Array<Repo>()
            for (_, jsonRepo) in json {
                let repo = Repo(json: jsonRepo)
                repos.append(repo)
            }

            return .Success(repos)
        } catch {
            return .Failure(error as NSError)
        }
    }
}

func responseRepoArray(completionHandler: Result<Array<Repo>, NSError> -> Void) -> Self {
    return response(responseSerializer: Request.repoArrayResponseSerializer(), completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

}

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: The error seems clear. What you do you think your small-letter `response` is?

Comment: Something around here `return response( ... ` doesn't seem right.

Comment: @genghiskhan Were you able to figure this out? I'm seeing the same error after updating to Xcode 8 beta 6 and Alamofire swift3 (updated today).

Comment: @blwinters have you found a solution? I have the same problem...

Comment: @Mat0 Honestly, I don't remember where in my project I needed this, but I haven't had the issue since updating to the latest `master` branch of Alamofire.

Comment: I have the latest master branch of Alamofire, but I'm still seeing this error :-/