# ResponseSerializer 'cannot call value of non-function type 'NSHTTPURLResponse?'' with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift3, swifty-json

I had been using the following code without issue until updating to Xcode 8 beta 6. It is similar to [this example](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#generic-response-object-serialization) from the Alamofire repository. This morning I updated my Alamofire library to the latest `swift3` branch, which is now compatible with beta 6. It shows the error: `Cannot call value of non-function type 'HTTPURLResponse?'` A similar question exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561183/cannot-call-value-of-non-function-type-nshttpurlresponse), but it is not based on the current version of Swift and Alamofire.

From what I understand, this error is because it thinks that I am trying to return the `Request` property `response` instead of the function `response(responseSerializer: <T>, completionHandler: <(Response<T.SerializedObject, T.ErrorObject>) -> Void>)` and it thinks this because of a type error in either the `responseSerializer` or `completionHandler` that I'm passing into the function.

How can I adjust this code to make it compatible with the function declaration and compiler?

I added `@escaping` to the completionHandler to correct the error.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

extension Alamofire.Request {
public func responseObject<T: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable>(_ completionHandler: @escaping (Response<T, NSError>) -> Void) -> Self {
    let responseSerializer = ResponseSerializer<T, NSError> { request, res, data, error in

        guard let responseData = data else {
            let error = DFError.error(withDFCode: .dataSerializationFailed, failureReason: "Data could not be serialized because input data was nil.")
            return .failure(error)
        }

        let jsonData: Any?
        do {
            jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])
        } catch  {
            let error = DFError.error(withDFCode: .jsonSerializationFailed, failureReason: "JSON could not be serialized into response object")
            return .failure(error)
        }

        let json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(jsonData!)
        if let newObject = T(json: json) {

            return .success(newObject)
        }

        let error = DFError.error(withDFCode: .jsonSerializationFailed, failureReason: "JSON could not be serialized into response object")
        return .failure(error)
    }

    return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    //Error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'HTTPURLResponse?'
}
}
```

Comment: Could you rename the parameter `response` in your closure to something else?

Comment: BTW, I suspect that [SE-0103](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0103-make-noescape-default.md) is what caused the problem for you in this case.

Comment: @J.Cocoe Thanks, but I just now updated the closure to `ResponseSerializer<T, NSError> { request, res, data, error in` and the error persists.

Comment: Yeah, it's picking the outside one.  Try changing the `return response(...)` to `return res(...)`, too?

Comment: @J.Cocoe Turns out that adding `@escaping` was the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to mark your `completionHandler` as `@escaping`.

Comment: Thanks! That did it.

Answer (score 3):

I was still seeing this error even after adding `@escaping` to the closure.  The issue I had was that I needed to change my extension declaration from `extension Alamofire.Request { }` to `extension Alamofire.DataRequest { }`.