# Alamofire Decodable serializer

Tags: serialization, alamofire

I am trying to update some code for a Alamofire custom response serializer I found this bit of code on "bits of cocoa".

```
extension Alamofire.Request {
    public func responseCollection<T: Decodable>(completionHandler: Response<[T], NSError> -> Void) -> Self {
        let responseSerializer = ResponseSerializer<[T], NSError> { request, response, data, error in

            guard error == nil else { return .Failure(error!) }

            let result = Alamofire
                .Request
                .JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
                .serializeResponse(request, response, data, error)

            switch result {
            case .Success(let value):
                do {
                    return .Success(try [T].decode(value))
                } catch {
                    return .Failure(Error.errorWithCode(.JSONSerializationFailed,
                                                        failureReason: "JSON parsing error, JSON: \(value)"))
                }
            case .Failure(let error): return.Failure(error)
            }
        }

        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

This is pre swift 3, and `Response<[T], NSError>` is now a single value specialization  `Response<[T]>` because of this I am not sure how this extension would translate for the changes to Alamofire on the swift 3

I started to update this code this is as far as I got

```
    extension Alamofire.Request {
        public func responseCollection<T: Decodable>(completionHandler: (Response<[T]>) -> Void) -> Self {
            let responseSerializer = ResponseSerializer<[T]> { request, response, data, error in

                guard error == nil else { return .failure(error!) }

                let result = Alamofire
                    .Request
                    .JSONResponseSerializer(options: .allowFragments)
                    .serializeResponse(request, response, data, error)

                switch result {
                case .success(let value):
                    do {
                        return .success(try [T].decode(value))
                    } catch {
                        return .failure(Error(.errorWithCode(.JSONSerializationFailed, failureReason: "JSON parsing error, JSON: \(value)")))
                    }
                case .failure(let error): return.failure(error)
                }
            }

            return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, com

pletionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

this get me 2 errors that at the moment I have not found any way to fix them:

1) for "`return .failure(Error(.errorWithCode(.JSONSerializationFailed, failureReason: "JSON parsing error, JSON: \(value)")))`", I am getting this error ('Error' cannot be constructed because it as no accessible initializers)

2) for "`return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)`", I am getting this error (Cannot call value of non-function type 'HTTPURLResponse')

Hopefully if any one can point me to a better solution then this bit of code or the correct fix for this. Thanks I will be working on this still, if I do fix it I will update this ticket.

**Edit - update**

So This is the code as of now

```
extension Alamofire.Request {
    public func responseDecodable<T: Decodable>(completionHandler: @escaping (Response<T>) -> Void) -> Self {
        let responseSerializer = ResponseSerializer<T> { request, response, data, error in

            guard error == nil else {
                print("error Network request: \(error)")
                return .failure(error!)
            }

            let result = Alamofire
                .Request
                .JSONResponseSerializer(options: .allowFragments)
                .serializeResponse(request, response, data, error)

            switch result {
            case .success(let value):
                do {
                    let decodableObject = try T.decode(value)
                    return .success(decodableObject)
                } catch let decodeErr {
                    print(decodeErr)
                    let failureReason = "JSON parsing error, JSON: \(value)"
                    let userInfo = [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: failureReason]
                    let error = NSError(domain: "com.prospects.error", code: BackendError.JSONSerializationFailed.rawValue, userInfo: userInfo)
                    return .failure(error)
                }
            case .failure(let error): return.failure(error)
            }
        }

        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}

public protocol ResponseObjectSerializable {
    init?(response: HTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject)
}
```

as per last comment : Response and ResponseSerializer are now unresolved, this used to work with no error yesterday. but updating xcode and alamofire this morning as made this to get errors now.

Comment: ok. I found this http://www.swiftbyexamples.com/2016/05/12/alamofire-custom-nserror-implementation-to-avoid-using-deprecated-errorwithcode-_-failurereason/ so this should fix error #1

Comment: for #2 I found this I think this will fix it. will know when I can test this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003875/responseserializer-cannot-call-value-of-non-function-type-nshttpurlresponse

Comment: Just as a note. the last code does work :)

Comment: Updating to the new xcode 8 GM and the latest Alamofire code, I am getting errors on `Response<T>` saying its now undeclared and `ResponseSerializer<T>` also unresolved. So I will need to re-fix this again.I will post a final answer to this un less some one can post one faster :)